# Density in Cartesian product.

Tags: general-topology

Let $H = \{0,1\}$ and consider the discrete topology. Now, let $I = [0,1]$ with the usual topology. Let $K$ be a subset of $H\times I$ which is dense. We can express $K$ as the union of $\{0\}\times U_{0}$ and $\{1\}\times U_{1}$, where $U_{0}, U_{1}\subseteq I$. As $K$ is dense, can we assert that $U_{0}$ and $U_{1}$ are also dense subsets of $I$?.

I have a possible proof. Suppose, by contradiction and w.l.o.g. that $U_{0}$ is not dense in $I$. Then, there exists $x_{0}\in I$ and $U_{x_{0}}$ a neighborhood of $x_{0}$ in $I$ such that $U\cap  U_{0} = \emptyset$.

Then, $\{0\}\times U$ is a neigborhood of $(0,x_{0})$ in $H\times I$ and

$$\{0\}\times U\cap K = (\{0\}\times U)\cap (\{0\}\times U_{0}) = \{0\}\cap (U\cap U_{0}) = \emptyset$$

Is it correct?

Answer (score 1):

It seems correct. A somehow shorter way is to observe that a subset $K$ of a topological space $X$ is dense if and only if $K\cap U$ is dense in $U$ for all open sets $U\subseteq X$, and $\{0\}\times [0,1]$ and $\{1\}\times [0,1]$ are open.

Answer (score 1):

No need for contradiction. If $U$ is open, non-empty in $[0,1]$, so is $\{0\} \times U$ in $H \times I$, so this set intersects $K$, by definition in some $(0,x)$ with $x \in U_0$. So $U_0$ intersects $U$ and so is dense. The same goes for $U_1$, using the open $\{1\} \times U$ instead.